# Update UITableView contents depending on UIPickerView selection

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

I have a View Controller containing a tableView with two sections. Section 1 has only one row, and Section 2 has some array with no limit on the number of rows.

When I click on the cell in Section 1, I have a pickerView appear in an Action Sheet. Whatever component I select on my pickerView becomes the Title on that Section 1 cell.

Now my question,

Can the contents of Section 2 of my tableView depend on the title text of the cell in Section 1?

For Example:

```
if Section 1's text is = "String A", Section 2's contents should be = "Array A"
if Section 1's text is = "String B", Section 2's contents should be = "Array B"
if Section 1's text is = "String C", Section 2's contents should be = "Array C"
if Section 1's text is = "String D", Section 2's contents should be = "Array D"
```

and so on...

Also, I would like the tableView to update its contents as I dismiss the pickerView with the desired String.
Some sample code/reference is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

One good solution would be to create an enum variable that stores the user's selection, then use that to determine the table view contents. Here is some sample code:

```
typedef enum { SelectionA, SelectionB, SelectionC } Selection;

@interface MyViewController : UITableViewController (UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate)

@property (nonatomic) Selection selection;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayA;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayB;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayC;

@end


@implementation MyViewController

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  NSInteger num = 0;
  if(section==0) {
    num = 1;
  }
  else {
    switch(self.selection)
    {
       case SelectionA: num = [self.arrayA count]; break;
       case SelectionB: num = [self.arrayB count]; break;
       case SelectionC: num = [self.arrayC count]; break;
    }
  }

  return num;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

  NSString *cellText = nil;
  if(indexPath.section==0) {
    switch(self.selection)
    {
       case SelectionA: cellText = @"String A"; break;
       case SelectionB: cellText = @"String A"; break;
       case SelectionC: cellText = @"String A"; break;
    }
  }
  else {
    switch(self.selection)
    {
       case SelectionA: cellText = [self.arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; break;
       case SelectionB: cellText = [self.arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; break;
       case SelectionC: cellText = [self.arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; break;
    }
  }

  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]
           initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }

  cell.textLabel.text = cellText;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

for set title of section 1

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)sender.superview;
   cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[self.listOfPickerData objectAtIndex:row]];

    [self customeMethod];
  [self.tabelView reloadData];
}
```

for your array base on selected piker view's row

```
-(void)customeMethod
{
    int row = [repeatPickerView selectedRowInComponent:0];
    self.selectedRowFromPicker = [repeatPickerData objectAtIndex:row];

   if([self.selectedRowFromPicker isEqualToString:@"piker row 1 "])
   {
     // NSArray *myArray1......
   }
   eles if([self.selectedRowFromPicker isEqualToString:@"piker row 2 "])
   {
     // NSArray *myArray2......
   }
   else
   {
     // NSArray *myArray3......
   }
}
```